# Swift, scrollview and textfield auto scroll when the keyboard appears

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have input form in popover.
When keyboard appears it shrinks in half..I have added in scroll view in base too but didn’t work..

**Initializing:**

```
var popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UnitEditController")  as! UnitEditController
popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(820, 820)
popoverViewController.unit = unit
popoverViewController.property = property
popoverViewController.unitDetailProtocolVar = self
let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController
var rect = CGRectMake(cell!.bounds.origin.x+500, cell!.bounds.origin.y+20, 50, 30);
popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = cell!.contentView
popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = cell!.frame
popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros
popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = rect
presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Prepare code for textfield and textview editing:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
let scrollSize = CGSizeMake(900, 820)
self.contentScrollView.contentSize = scrollSize  
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.contentScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, -300, 320, 700);
}
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, +300, 320, 700);
}
```

it should auto scroll accordingly when i start editing textview and textfield.
Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 2):

this is what I did:

I created a keyboardHandler class

```
class KeyboardUtils{

    static var instance = KeyboardUtils();
    static var lastKeyboardSize : CGSize = CGSize();
    var keyBoarEventsCallBacks : [(onShow: ()->Void,onHide: ()->Void)] = [];

    init(){

        self._registerKeyboardHandler()
        KeyboardUtils.instance = self;
    }


    private func _registerKeyboardHandler(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0);
            KeyboardUtils.lastKeyboardSize = keyboardSize.size;

            for i in self.keyBoarEventsCallBacks{
                i.onShow();
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
            for i in self.keyBoarEventsCallBacks{
                i.onHide();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this class will handle event when keyboard is opened.

now from my scrollView class i did this:

```
class myScrollView : UIScrollView,UIScrollViewDelegate{

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        KeyboardUtils.instance.keyBoarEventsCallBacks.append((onShow:self.onKeyboardAppear,onHide: self.onKeyboardHide));

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func onKeyboardAppear(){
        //I just resized, you can also do super.contentOffset =...
        var size = super.contentSize;

        size.height+=KeyboardUtils.lastKeyboardSize.height;
        super.contentSize = size;
    }

    func onKeyboardHide(){
        var size = super.contentSize;

        size.height-=KeyboardUtils.height;
        super.contentSize = size;
    }
}
```

and now every time the keyboard will open, you'll have callback function to your UIViewScroll class. +it'll know the keyboard size that opened, because keyboard sizes might be different from phone to phone

edit:
you don't have to use custom view class, you can register any class

```
class myClass : anyClass{

    override init(...)
    {
        super.init(...)
 //on ViewController class do it on ViewDidLoad 
      KeyboardUtils.instance.keyBoarEventsCallBacks.append((onShow:self.onKeyboardAppear,onHide: self.onKeyboardHide));

    }

    func onKeyboardAppear(){

        let keyboardSize =KeyboardUtils.lastKeyboardSize.height;
        //do your stuff
    }

    func onKeyboardHide(){
        let keyboardSize =KeyboardUtils.lastKeyboardSize.height;
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel Krom, Do i have to create myScrollView other than my controller?

Comment: you can also register your view controller, just add onKeyboardHide and onKeybboardShow to your viewController and handle callbacks from there

added an edit with example

Comment: Daniel Krom, It gets hanged when i call  this in viewdidLoad......KeyboardUtils.instance.keyBoarEventsCallBacks.append((onShow:self.onKeyboardAppear,onHide: self.onKeyboardHide)) ..am i doing something wronge?

Comment: ok, well it shouldn't where are you registering to keyboardutils? can you post your code?

Comment: yes sure i will..in addition to that can we make it you code in same controller...if we want to keep keyboard size same(static)?